# Websocket is not working properly when we switched another page in React

Tags: reactjs, websocket

I’m currently working on building a React website that utilizes websockets. In my code, I create a WebSocket object and pass it through React context. Here’s a snippet of what I have:

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

const WebSocketContext = createContext();

const WebSocketProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = Cookies.get('token');
    if (token) {
      const newSocket = new WebSocket(import.meta.env.VITE_SOCKET_URL + token);
      setSocket(newSocket);
      return () => {
        newSocket.close();
      };
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <WebSocketContext.Provider value={socket}>
      {children}
    </WebSocketContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { WebSocketProvider, WebSocketContext };
```

However, I’m encountering an issue: while the initial page works fine and I can receive messages properly, when I navigate to another page, the websocket starts behaving inconsistently. Some messages are captured, but others are not. I’ve checked the backend logs, and it seems that the messages are being sent correctly. My backend server also works as expected during Postman tests.

I’m using the following code to handle incoming messages in each component:

```
socket.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  console.log("Message received:", event.data);
});
```

Could you please help me identify potential causes for this issue? I’m only using React JS for this project. Thank you!